# Executing a WebClient request ends with an error connection reset

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, netty, webclient

I'm using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.6.9` and `WebClient` to make requests in **synchronous** mode (as a replacement for `RestTemplate`). When making a small number of requests through the `WebClient`, everything works fine, but as soon as the number of requests increases, then some of the requests start to get an error:

```
2023-06-23 15:03:50.603 WARN [] 45045 --- [reactor-http-] r.n.h.client.HttpClientConnect : [74630f62-1, L:/192.168.23.3:57614 - R:some-http-url/1.2.3.4:443] The connection observed an error    
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:258)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:350)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
.........
Caused by: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET https://some-http-url[DefaultWebClient]
```

My WebClient config looks like this:

```java
ConnectionProvider provider = ConnectionProvider.builder("some-provider")
        .maxConnections(properties.getMaxConnections())
        .maxIdleTime(properties.getMaxIdleTime())
        .maxLifeTime(properties.getMaxLifeTime())
        .pendingAcquireTimeout(properties.getPendingAcquireTimeout())
        .evictInBackground(properties.getEvictInBackground())
        .build();

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create(provider)
        .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 5000)
        .responseTimeout(properties.getResponseTimeout())
        .doOnConnected(conn -> conn.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(properties.getReadTimeout()))
                .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(properties.getWriteTimeout())));

final ExchangeStrategies strategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder()
        .codecs(codecs -> codecs.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize((int) maxInMemorySize.toBytes()))
        .build();

WebClient.builder()
        .exchangeStrategies(strategies)
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
        .baseUrl(properties.getUrl())
        .filter(authExchangeFilterFunction)
        .filter(logRequest())
        .filter(logResponse())
        .filter(ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(errorHandlingProcessor()))
        .build();
```

I tried changing the settings (max-connection, max-idle-time, max-life-time, etc...), but that didn't help.

The call to the API method itself looks like this:

```java
webClient.get()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("some-path/{param}").build(param))
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(DataBuffer.class)
        .<file>handle((dataBuffer, sink) -> {
                try {
                        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
                        sink.next((file) unmarshaller.unmarshal(dataBuffer.asInputStream()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        sink.error(new CustomException(e.getMessage()));
                } finally {
                        DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
                }
        })
        .block();
```

Maybe someone can explain why a connection reset can occur?
A bit of context on increasing the number of requests:
I use the rabbitmq listener in the application and when I have the listener running in single-threaded mode, then the requests are processed correctly. But when I raise the number of listeners to 3-5+, errors start to appear.

Comment: is it possible that your client is overwhelming the server with requests and that the server is closing connections because there are too many? Is there a rate limit on this API? Does changing the max connections setting helps to limit the number of concurrent connections to this server?

Comment: @BrianClozel sorry for the long answer. Yes, this option is possible. Do you have any idea how this can be confirmed if there is no contact with the API developer?

Comment: if you change the max connections configuration in the connection pool to limit the number of concurrent connections - and that this change makes the API calls work consistently, I think this proves it. Logging more information at the reactor netty level will only show connections being closed so you probably won't learn more.

Comment: @BrianClozel I'm sorry to bring this up again, but maybe you can give me some advice again.
For me, the SocketException error actually occurs because the remote server is closing the connection. But I have no way to influence this remote server and I would like to somehow correctly handle this error on my side. The ideal option for me is to add retry for such requests. But when using spring-retry or retryWhen, it seems that it is not possible to transfer control to the code responsible for retry. You don't know why this might be or how it can be solved?

Comment: @BrianClozel The error in the log now looks something like this: https://i.imgur.com/1qZZudW.png